# Passing arguments to a function within an if statement in bash

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I am trying to pass arguments to a function within an `if` statement and then evaluating what the function returns (in bash).  The result I am getting is incorrect.  How do you properly do this?

```
#!/bin/bash

foo() {
    if [ $1 = "zero" ]; then
        echo "0"
    else 
        echo "1"
fi
}

arg="zero"
if foo $arg -eq 0 ; then
    echo "entered 0"
else
    echo "entered something else"
fi

arg="blah"
if foo $arg -eq 0 ; then
    echo "entered 0"
else
    echo "entered something else"
fi
```

Not the desired results:

```
cknight@macbook:~/work$ ./test.sh
0
entered 0
1
entered 0
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can either `return` a result from your function or use `$()` to capture its output:

```
if [ $(foo $arg) -eq 0 ] ; then
```

Comment: What if I am using multiple functions within the if statement with && or ||? In that case this does not work.

Comment: @7heViking Then definitely prefer the `return` form but instead of capturing the output, examine the returned value.  Basically, `if foo "$arg"; then` (notice also the proper quoting of the argument).

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure you need your function to echo 0 or 1? It looks more like you want something like

```
foo() {
  if [ $1 = "zero" ]; then
    return 0
  else 
    return 1
  fi
}

# Or even just simply foo () { [ $1 = "zero ]; }

arg="zero"
if foo $arg; then
    echo "entered 0"
else
    echo "entered something else"
fi

arg="blah"
if foo $arg; then
    echo "entered 0"
else
    echo "entered something else"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want to do...

Your `foo()` function always returns with success, use `return`.

You pass to your `foo()` function a second and a third parameter `-eq 0` but they aren't used. Do you want to check the exit status? That's simply `if foo $arg; then ..; fi`.